# Synchronous ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've made a form to register a new account. In this form I'm checking if the email chosen is available or not, but I'm checking that with a webservice it takes a few seconds.
Let's see that beautiful method :

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(re.test(email) == true) {
        var status;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/checkEmail.php",
            data: "email="+email,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 30000
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $(".spinner").hide();
            status = msg;
        });
        return status;
    }
}
```

I've been forced to put async to false unless the function didn't wait my ajax to be done and returned nothing. With that async:false, he does but my whole front is blocked until the loading's end (my mouse is blocked and I can't fill any others fields).

I'm sure I'm not the first one to be confronted to that situation so I'm counting on you mates :-) !

Thanks !

Comment: `async:false` - no! - You want an async request so you don't completely lock the client if something goes haywire on the backend!

Comment: Because async operations *don't do returns*. You give them *to-do* functions, called *callbacks*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the asynchronous method, but have the return function enable the "Submit" button (or equivalent).

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(re.test(email) == true) {
        var status;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/checkEmail.php",
            data: "email="+email,
            timeout: 30000
        }).done(function( data ) {
            //move your result processing here
            checkResult(data);
        });
        return status;
    }
}

function checkResult(svcdata) {
     $(".spinner").hide();
     status = msg;
    //code here to check the result value and enable further action
    if (svcdata.approved) {  
        $("#submitid").attr("disabled",false);
    } else {
        $("#submidid").attr("disabled",true);
        //other alerting methods (highlight field, refocus, etc)
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of people have mentioned callbacks, and that's a very powerful way of getting the job done.  However, when you're trying to do something atomic (specific to that call only), this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You never `return` the result of the AJAX method like you're doing, instead you would pass a callback and keep `async:true`

```
function validateEmail(email, callback) {
...
...
}).done(function( data ) {
    $(".spinner").hide();
    status = data;
    callback(status);
});
```

And your callback

```
function doWork(status) {
    console.log(status);
}
```

And how you call that:

```
validateEmail(email, doWork);
```

Comment: Did you realize that "msg" should actually be "data" since msg isn't set anywhere and is not what the ajax call returns?

Comment: @ITroubs - Hah, missed that, changing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

$.when(ajaxCall).then(function(response){})

Answer (score 0):

you can use promises:

```
<script>
$.postData = function(url, form_data) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).promise();
};
$.postData("your_url", "your_form_data").then(function (data) {
    // do whatever you have to do with data
});
</script>
```